# Check if file exists - XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm sorry but any past discussions or googling about this topic didn't help me, so I need to ask you in new one.

User has some option. There is a form for sending messages and he may send a message with or without attachment from the server and if the file doesnt exist (PDF), the user cant choose "with attachment" option.

The XMLHttpRequest() is the place from where I can't move.

Here is some code, please tell me I have to do.

```
                $('.radio-msg-type').on('click', function(){
                        if($('#fullQuotation').is(':checked')) {
                                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                http.open("GET",pdf_file,true);
                                http.send();
                                if ( http.status==404 ) {
                                   alert('not found');
                                } else {
                                   alert('found');
                                }
                        }
                if($('#justMessage').is(':checked')) {
                        }
                });
```

Comment: The server should be doing this when the page is loaded.

Comment: Since the request is asynchronous, you'll have to use its events to test the response -- [`.onload`, `.onerror`, and/or `.onreadystatechange`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handlers).

Comment: @Diodeus, yes, it is, but there is a chance to "lose" the file when the user is using the page.. I'd be happy if it could be verified on click.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I thougt that open("","",true) indicates synchronous request. And maybe I'm looking like an idiot but this is something very unknown to me...:/

Comment: @user3424754 [You'll have to pass `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()) as the 3rd argument to have a synchronous request. The default for that argument is `true`, so you can think of it as having to explicitly opt-out to change modes.

Comment: Perfect, thank you just type it as an answer and i will accept.
`http.open("GET",pdf_file,false);
http.send();
if ( http.status==404 ) { alert('not found');}
    else { alert('found');}`

Comment: @ And thank you for direction (W3)

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, you might as well take advantage of its `$.ajax` function.

```
$('.radio-msg-type').on('click', function(){
  if ($('#fullQuotation').is(':checked')) {
    $.ajax({
      url: pdf_file,
      type: 'HEAD'
    }).done(function(){
      alert('found');
    }).fail(function(){
      alert('not found');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've already tried this solution before, but it didn't working. Depends the functionality on used version of jQuery? I mean it sure do, but what about 1.8.3?